# how to remove 0 (zero) from the day and month but not from the year (01/09/2012) using in Linux (Redhat)

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

Using Linux (Redhat)

When I use  dialog: --calendar to output the date.
The format will be `dd/mm/yyyy` but I need the format to be `d/m/yyyy` for day and month numbers smaller than 10.

Example
Output: `01/09/2012`
Result: `1/9/2012`

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I tried using tr -d '0,' but it will also remove the 0 from the year as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed`. Here it removes all leading `0`'s appearing at the beginning of every "word": `\<`.

```
$ echo 01/09/2012 | sed 's/\<0//g'
1/9/2012
```

You might also used `\b` which match any word boundary:

```
$ echo 01/09/2012 | sed 's/\b0//g'
1/9/2012
```

Comment: What does `\<` means?

Comment: @mohammad.k Answer updated.

Comment: About word boundaries: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html